# Moving output files generated by a program to a specific directory using shell scripting

Tags: shell-script

I have a program that generates a bunch of files. I want the files generated by this program to be moved into a sub-directory. I am looking for shell scripting ideas other than the rudimentary method of using `mv` statement for each file.

Comment: What else have you found and tried? What is wrong with `mv`? Can the program that creates the files be reprogrammed to write those files into a subdirectory?

Comment: I am not aware of other methods as I am very new to shell scripting. I have tried to use the `find` command to get the latest `n` files generated so that I can move them all but was not able to succeed. The reason for not going with `mv` is because there are a lot files that are generated with arbitrary names. It would not be a good idea to move each of the manually.

Comment: so find a pattern in the filenames and move them programmatically in a loop, or move everything in the directory at once if you want to move everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a program writes files is an implementation of that program and is generally not influenced by shells.  But here are a few ideas:

- If the program generates contents on stdout, you can use the `>` operator to store those contents in another location.  Example:

```
myprogram > /path/to/subdir/file
```

- The program may have command-line options so you can define where the output goes.  In this case I am compiling `main.c` into `prog` and instead of storing it in the present-working-directory, I've asked it to be sent to `./subdir/`

```
$ gcc main.c -o ./subdir/prog
```

- If the program always writes to the present working directory, you could run the program from your target location.  The following is similar to the previous example, but run from `./subdir/`. In this case, you could run:

```
$ gcc ../main.c -o prog
```

It's common for windows applications, or programs written by people new to linux to rely on resources relative to `.`, but usually on linux applications that isn't an issue.  If the program writes to `.` and doesn't rely on resources relative to `.`, then run it from the directory you're interested in.  If it's not in `$PATH` you may need to specify the full path the to binary.

---

The location of output files is not really a function of the shell.  It's a function of what you're running.  As an example, If I write a simple C program which writes "Hello" into a log file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   FILE * fp = fopen ("/var/log/mylog","w");
   fprintf (fp, "Hello\n");
   fclose (fp);
   return 0;
}
```

You can see that the output file is a hard-coded path.  The shell cannot influence that.